# After redirecting to another URL , how to capture the response/status codes in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, callback, response, http-response-codes

I have below piece of code in an extjs window items,

```
 {
                xtype: "component",
                autoEl: {
                    tag: "iframe",
                    src: https://google.com
                }
            }
```

When clicked on the window it will redirect to another URL(Ex: https://google.com).
Once it redirects to external URL , i want to capture the response or status code.
How can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Callback based on external URL response in extjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507917/how-to-add-callback-based-on-external-url-response-in-extjs)

Comment: I am not sure for this approach, but you can try a Ext Ajax request for same URL(of Iframe), and check response there.You can call this code inside setInterval().